# Document Count of a Word in Spark/Scala

Tags: apache-spark

I have a text variable which is an RDD of String in scala

```
val data = sc.parallelize(List("i am a good boy.Are you a good boy.","You are also working here.","I am posting here today.You are good."))
```

I have another variable in Scala Map(given below)

//list of words for which doc count needs to be found,initial doc count is 1

```
val dictionary = Map( """good""" -> 1,"""working""" -> 1,"""posting""" -> 1 ).
```

I want to do a document count of each of the dictionary terms and get the output in key value format

My output should be like below for the above data.

```
(good,2)

(working,1)

(posting,1)
```

What i have tried is

```
dictionary.map { case(k,v) => k -> k.r.findFirstIn(data.map(line => line.trim()).collect().mkString(",")).size}
```

I am getting counts as 1 for all the words.

Please help me in fixing the above line

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use flatMap to create the dictionary and then you can query that.

```
val dictionary = data.flatMap {case line => line.split(" ")}.map {case word => (word, 1)}.reduceByKey(_+_)
```

If I collect this in the REPL I get the following result:

```
res9: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((here,1), (good.,1), (good,2), (here.,1), (You,1), (working,1), (today.You,1), (boy.Are,1), (are,2), (a,2), (posting,1), (i,1), (boy.,1), (also,1), (I,1), (am,2), (you,1))
```

Obviously you would need to do a better split than in my simple example.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your dictionary should be a Set, because in general sense you need to map the Set of terms to the number of documents which contain them.

So your data should look like:

```
scala> val docs = List("i am a good boy.Are you a good boy.","You are also working here.","I am posting here today.You are good.")
docs: List[String] = List(i am a good boy.Are you a good boy., You are also working here., I am posting here today.You are good.)
```

Your dictionary should look like:

```
scala> val dictionary = Set("good", "working", "posting")
dictionary: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(good, working, posting)
```

Then you have to implement your transformation, for the simplest logic of the `contains` function it might look like:

```
scala> dictionary.map(k => k -> docs.count(_.contains(k))) toMap
res4: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(good -> 2, working -> 1, posting -> 1)
```

For better solution I'd recommend you to implement specific function for your requirements

> (String, String) => Boolean

to determine the presence of the term in the document:

```
scala> def foo(doc: String, term: String): Boolean = doc.contains(term)
foo: (doc: String, term: String)Boolean
```

Then final solution will look like:

```
scala> dictionary.map(k => k -> docs.count(d => foo(d, k))) toMap
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(good -> 2, working -> 1, posting -> 1)
```

The last thing you have to do is to calculate the result map using SparkContext. First of all you have to define what data you want to have parallelised. Let's assume we want to parallelize the collection of the documents, then solution might be like following:

```
val docsRDD = sc.parallelize(List(
    "i am a good boy.Are you a good boy.", 
    "You are also working here.", 
    "I am posting here today.You are good."
))
docsRDD.mapPartitions(_.map(doc => dictionary.collect {
  case term if doc.contains(term) => term -> 1
})).map(_.toMap) reduce { case (m1, m2) => merge(m1, m2) }

def merge(m1: Map[String, Int], m2: Map[String, Int]) =
  m1 ++ m2 map { case (k, v) => k -> (v + m1.getOrElse(k, 0)) }
```